# Change size tiles SCSS

Tags: html, css, templates, sass

I am quite new to html and CSS, but I have learned several things while crafting my [webpage](https://panopepino.github.io/web_page/) based on this [template](https://html5up.net/phantom). I would like to enhance by changing the f**orm of the tiles to be rectangles instead of squares**, so it looks better when using small screens.

These are the lines of code I consider relevant:

- This is in the main.css file.

```
* Tiles */

.tiles {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    margin: -2.5em 0 0 -2.5em;
}

    .tiles article {
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        position: relative;
        width: calc(33.33333% - 2.5em);
        margin: 2.5em 0 0 2.5em;
    }

        .tiles article > .image {
            -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
            -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 4px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            .tiles article > .image img {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .tiles article > .image:before {
                -moz-pointer-events: none;
                -webkit-pointer-events: none;
                -ms-pointer-events: none;
                pointer-events: none;
                -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
                -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
                -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
                transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
                content: '';
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                opacity: 1.0;
                z-index: 1;
                opacity: 0.8;
            }

            .tiles article > .image:after {
                -moz-pointer-events: none;
                -webkit-pointer-events: none;
                -ms-pointer-events: none;
                pointer-events: none;
                -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
                -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
                -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
                transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
                content: '';
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cstyle%3Eline %7B stroke-width: 0.25px%3B stroke: %23ffffff%3B %7D%3C/style%3E%3Cline x1='0' y1='0' x2='100' y2='100' /%3E%3Cline x1='100' y1='0' x2='0' y2='100' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                opacity: 0.25;
                z-index: 2;
            }

        .tiles article > a {
            display: -moz-flex;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flex;
            display: flex;
            -moz-flex-direction: column;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
            -moz-align-items: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            -ms-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
            -moz-justify-content: flex-start;
            -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
            -ms-justify-content: flex-start;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
            -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
            -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
            transition: background-color 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 1em;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom: 0;
            color: #314F00;
            text-align: centre;
            text-decoration: none;
            z-index: 3;
        }

            .tiles article > a > :last-child {
                margin: 0;
            }

            .tiles article > a:hover {
                color: #ffffff !important;
            }

            .tiles article > a h2 {
                margin: 0;
            }

            .tiles article > a .content {
                -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
                -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
                -ms-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
                transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
                width: 100%;
                max-height: 0;
                line-height: 1.5;
                margin-top: 0.35em;
                opacity: 0;
            }

                .tiles article > a .content > :last-child {
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                }

        .tiles article.style1 > .image:before {
            /* background-color: #f2849e; */
            background-image:url(images\one-man-tent.jpg);
        }

        .tiles article.style2 > .image:before {
            /*background-color: #7ecaf6;*/
            background-image:url(images\two-man-tent.jpg);
        }

        .tiles article.style3 > .image:before {
            /*background-color: #7bd0c1;*/
            background-image:url(images\group-tent.jpg);
        }

        .tiles article.style4 > .image:before {
            /*background-color: #c75b9b;*/
            background-image:url(images\camping-gear.jpg);
        }

        .tiles article.style5 > .image:before {
            /*background-color: #ae85ca;*/
            background-image:url(images\camping-checklist.jpg);
        }

        .tiles article.style6 > .image:before {
            /*background-color: #8499e7;*/
            background-image:url(images\campsites.jpg);
        }

        body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image {
            -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }

            body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image:before {
                background-color: #333333;
                opacity: 0.35;
            }

            body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image:after {
                opacity: 0;
            }

        body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover .content {
            max-height: 15em;
            opacity: 1;
        }

    * + .tiles {
        margin-top: 2em;
    }

    body.is-loading .tiles article {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    body.is-touch .tiles article .content {
        max-height: 15em;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {

        .tiles {
            margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
        }

            .tiles article {
                width: calc(33.33333% - 1.25em);
                margin: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
            }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

        .tiles {
            margin: -2.5em 0 0 -2.5em;
        }

            .tiles article {
                width: calc(50% - 2.5em);
                margin: 2.5em 0 0 2.5em;
            }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 736px) {

        .tiles {
            margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
        }

            .tiles article {
                width: calc(50% - 1.25em);
                margin: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
            }

                .tiles article:hover > .image {
                    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
                    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
                    transform: scale(1.0);
                }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

        .tiles {
            margin: 0;
        }

            .tiles article {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 1.25em 0 0 0;
            }

    }
```

- This is the specific tiles.scss file:

```
.tiles {
    $gutter: _size(gutter);
    $duration: 0.5s;
    $ease: 'ease';

    @include vendor('display', 'flex');
    @include vendor('flex-wrap', 'wrap');
    postiion: relative;
    margin: ($gutter * -1) 0 0 ($gutter * -1);

    article {
        @include vendor('transition', (
            'transform #{$duration} #{$ease}',
            'opacity #{$duration} #{$ease}'
        ));
        position: relative;
        width: calc(#{(100% / 3)} - #{$gutter * 1});
        margin: $gutter 0 0 $gutter;

        > .image {
            @include vendor('transition', 'transform #{$duration} #{$ease}');
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: _size(border-radius);
            overflow: hidden;

            img {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }

            &:before {
                @include vendor('pointer-events', 'none');
                @include vendor('transition', (
                    'background-color #{$duration} #{$ease}',
                    'opacity #{$duration} #{$ease}'
                ));
                content: '';
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                opacity: 1.0;
                z-index: 1;
                opacity: 0.8;
            }

            &:after {
                @include vendor('pointer-events', 'none');
                @include vendor('transition', 'opacity #{$duration} #{$ease}');
                content: '';
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-image: svg-url('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"><style>line { stroke-width: 0.25px; stroke: #ffffff; }</style><line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" /><line x1="100" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" /></svg>');
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                opacity: 0.25;
                z-index: 2;
            }
        }

        > a {
            @include vendor('display', 'flex');
            @include vendor('flex-direction', 'column');
            @include vendor('align-items', 'center');
            @include vendor('justify-content', 'center');
            @include vendor('transition', (
                'background-color #{$duration} #{$ease}',
                'transform #{$duration} #{$ease}'
            ));
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 1em;
            border-radius: _size(border-radius);
            border-bottom: 0;
            color: _palette(fg-accent);
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            z-index: 3;

            > :last-child {
                margin: 0;
            }

            &:hover {
                color: _palette(fg-accent) !important;
            }

            h2 {
                margin: 0;
            }

            .content {
                @include vendor('transition', (
                    'max-height #{$duration} #{$ease}',
                    'opacity #{$duration} #{$ease}'
                ));
                width: 100%;
                max-height: 0;
                line-height: 1.5;
                margin-top: 0.35em;
                opacity: 0;

                > :last-child {
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                }
            }
        }

        &.style1 {
            > .image:before {
                background-color: _palette(accent1);
            }
        }

        &.style2 {
            > .image:before {
                background-color: _palette(accent2);
            }
        }

        &.style3 {
            > .image:before {
                background-color: _palette(accent3);
            }
        }

        &.style4 {
            > .image:before {
                background-color: _palette(accent4);
            }
        }

        &.style5 {
            > .image:before {
                background-color: _palette(accent5);
            }
        }

        &.style6 {
            > .image:before {
                background-color: _palette(accent6);
            }
        }

        body:not(.is-touch) & {
            &:hover {
                > .image {
                    @include vendor('transform', 'scale(1.1)');

                    &:before {
                        background-color: _palette(bg-accent);
                        opacity: 0.35;
                    }

                    &:after {
                        opacity: 0;
                    }
                }

                .content {
                    max-height: 15em;
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    * + & {
        margin-top: _size(element-margin);
    }

    body.is-loading & {
        article {
            @include vendor('transform', 'scale(0.9)');
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    body.is-touch & {
        article {
            .content {
                max-height: 15em;
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }

    @include breakpoint(large) {
        $gutter: _size(gutter) * 0.5;

        margin: ($gutter * -1) 0 0 ($gutter * -1);

        article {
            width: calc(#{(100% / 3)} - #{$gutter * 1});
            margin: $gutter 0 0 $gutter;
        }
    }

    @include breakpoint(medium) {
        $gutter: _size(gutter);

        margin: ($gutter * -1) 0 0 ($gutter * -1);

        article {
            width: calc(#{(100% / 2)} - #{$gutter * 1});
            margin: $gutter 0 0 $gutter;
        }
    }

    @include breakpoint(small) {
        $gutter: _size(gutter) * 0.5;

        margin: ($gutter * -1) 0 0 ($gutter * -1);

        article {
            width: calc(#{(100% / 2)} - #{$gutter * 1});
            margin: $gutter 0 0 $gutter;

            &:hover {
                > .image {
                    @include vendor('transform', 'scale(1.0)');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @include breakpoint(xsmall) {
        $gutter: _size(gutter) * 0.5;

        margin: 0;

        article {
            width: 100%;
            margin: $gutter 0 0 0;
        }
    }
}
```

- I have tried to modify .tiles article in the main.css adding a height command, but nothing happens.
- I managed to get the rectangular shape by adding a height command of 50% in .tiles article .image, and moving the text upwards, but the square tile shape remains and new tiles in the second row are far away.
- I would like to reduce the "box" around the tile to half its height, yet these rectangle tiles to pile up as the default square ones.

Thanks in advance for your help.